# How to override existing quantity already in cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Problem I am having here is that people go to a Product page, set a quantity on how much they want of that product and add to cart (which than takes them to the cart page).  Client wants the ability to go back to the shop/product page if they want to make further changes to that product (honestly this is strange, since they can do this on the cart page, but whatever).  But when people go to update the quantity on the product page, instead of updating the quantity, it adds to the existing quantity for that product.

How to get it to update the existing quantity when the quantity has been submitted more than once on the product page?  Is there a woocommerce loop that I can take advantage of here?

Comment: I agree this is very strange and seems like a lot of work for no benefit. Maybe tell your client you will have to charge a lot of money to accomplish this AND it will result in bad user experience.

Comment: Yeah, they are set in their ways...  not changing their mind :(

Comment: I can't think of how you'd do this without disabling the regular add to cart actions. Best guess would be to add a hidden input on a product page if the product is in the cart... maybe the cart key itself? Then use that input to set up a custom add to cart handler by filtering `woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler`. This requires WC2.3 (dev version available at github) and then use the new handler to adjust the quantity somehow. It's rough and probably not easy, so I hope you are charging accordingly. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, just had to add the handler action, and tada... answered it below, in case anyone else is interested.  Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I have dug through the plugin and coded the solution below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'update_product_in_cart', 11, 2);

function update_product_in_cart($p, $q) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartItem = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;
    $currentProductId = $q->id;
    $wCart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    // If cart already exists, and product exists, than remove product, and add the new product to it.
    if ($wCart)
    {
        $cart_item_keys = array_keys($wCart);

        foreach($cart_item_keys as $key)
        {
            foreach($cartItem as $item)
            {
                $productItemId = $item['product_id'];
                if ($productItemId == $currentProductId)
                {
                    // If you want to empty the entire cart...
                    // $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                    // If you want to remove just the product from the cart...
                    $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($key, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // This adds the product to the cart...
    return $q;
}
```

This gets added to functions.php, and basically, if the product id exists in the cart, it removes the product and the return of `$q` adds in the new product info.

Works a charm!

Comment: Nice work! Btw- you don't need to use the global `$woocommerce` any more. You can now use the function `WC()` to grab the single instance of the main plugin class.

Comment: Exactly. If you look at the main plugin file at the very bottom you will see `$GLOBALS['woocommerce'] = WC();` which is there for backcompatibilty.

Comment: Thanks many... accidentally deleted my comment... argg, Cheers :)

Comment: This caused: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Product_Simple could not be converted to string.  Changing the return $q; to return $q->id; made the error go away, though i am not sure this is a good fix.