# How to Overriding the existing quantity of products already in cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, overriding, cart, product-quantity

I am using the latest version of wordpress and Woocommerce. 
My Functionality is " Overriding the existing Quantity of Products already in cart". I already try this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850763/how-to-override-existing-quantity-already-in-cart) but its failure. See the Code and its errors.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'update_product_in_cart', 11, 2);
function update_product_in_cart($p, $q) {
global $woocommerce;
$cartItem = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;
$currentProductId = $q->id;
$wCart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// If cart already exists, and product exists, than remove product, and add the new product to it.
if ($wCart)
{
    $cart_item_keys = array_keys($wCart);

    foreach($cart_item_keys as $key)
    {
        foreach($cartItem as $item)
        {
            $productItemId = $item['product_id'];
            if ($productItemId == $currentProductId)
            {
                // If you want to empty the entire cart...
                // $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                // If you want to remove just the product from the cart...
                $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($key, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
// This adds the product to the cart...
return $q;
}
```

Its Error is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Product_Grouped could not be converted to string in plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-form-handler.php on line 715
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with some code, WC_Product_Grouped returns an object, something in your code treat some data as a string the can come if you want to concenate the object like a string.

Comment: This is the code I am using. Not only for grouped products also for single product page.

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'update_product_in_cart', 11, 2);function update_product_in_cart($p, $q) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartItem = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;
    $currentProductId = $q->id;
    $wCart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    if ($wCart){
        $cart_item_keys = array_keys($wCart);
        foreach($cart_item_keys as $key)
        {foreach($cartItem as $item)
        {$productItemId = $item['product_id'];
        if ($productItemId == $currentProductId)
        {$woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($key, 0);
        }}}}return $q;
}

Answer (score 0):

This code is the answer, Previously I added on comment boxes....

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'update_product_in_cart', 11, 2);function update_product_in_cart($p, $q) { global $woocommerce; $cartItem = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents; $currentProductId = $q->id; $wCart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); if ($wCart){ $cart_item_keys = array_keys($wCart); foreach($cart_item_keys as $key) {foreach($cartItem as $item) {$productItemId = $item['product_id']; if ($productItemId == $currentProductId) {$woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($key, 0); }}}}return $q; }